# Custom CAGradientLayer doesn't animate

Tags: ios, caanimation, cagradientlayer

I've made a custom class of CAGradientLayer (added radial gradient option).
I works but I can't figure out why I can't animate the colors.

Here's my code.

The animation is a simple CABasicAnimation where I set the toValue to a new array with colors.

```
#import "ExtCAGradientLayer.h"

NSString * const kExt_CAGradientLayerRadial = @"RadialGradient";

@implementation ExtCAGradientLayer
@synthesize gradientDrawingOptions;

+(BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key
{
   return [key isEqualToString:@"type"] || [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)theContext
{
   if ([self.type isEqualToString:kExt_CAGradientLayerRadial]) {
    size_t num_locations = self.locations.count;

    int numbOfComponents = 0;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = NULL;

    if (self.colors.count) {
        CGColorRef colorRef = (__bridge CGColorRef)[self.colors objectAtIndex:0];
        numbOfComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(colorRef);
        colorSpace = CGColorGetColorSpace(colorRef);
    }

    float *locations = calloc(num_locations, sizeof(float));
    float *components = calloc(num_locations, numbOfComponents * sizeof(float));

    for (int x = 0; x < num_locations; x++) {
        locations[x] = [[self.locations objectAtIndex:x] floatValue];
        const CGFloat *comps = CGColorGetComponents((__bridge CGColorRef)[self.colors objectAtIndex:x]);
        for (int y = 0; y < numbOfComponents; y++) {
            int shift = numbOfComponents * x;
            components[shift + y] = comps[y];
        }
    }

    CGPoint position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
    CGFloat radius = floorf(MIN(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height) / 2);
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(theContext, gradient, position, 0, position, radius, self.gradientDrawingOptions);

    free(locations);
    free(components);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Layers have a bunch of implicit animations tied to them. This can make them a little funny when interacting with `CABasicAnimation`. My first recommendation is to avoid `CABasicAnimation` when working with layers. There's almost never a good reason for it, since layers know how to animate themselves. It's much easier just to do this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:3];
layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              (__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
              [UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
              nil]; 
[CATransaction commit];
```

That's a 3-second animation of the colors. Easy. The begin/commit aren't technically needed in most cases, but they limit the scope of the `setAnimationDuration:` in case you're animating other things in this transaction.

But maybe you like `CABasicAnimation`, or you're using it something that returns them (I do that sometimes). You can still combine them with `CALayer`, but you have to tell `CALayer` to stop its automatic animation (`setDisableActions:`). And you still want to use the layer setters rather than `toValue:`.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
CABasicAnimation *anim = [[CABasicAnimation alloc] init];
anim.duration = 3;
[layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"colors"];
layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                (__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                [UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
                nil];
[CATransaction commit];
```

If you use `toValue:` rather than the setter, it will work, but will "jump back" to the original value at the end.

Avoid solutions that suggest setting `fillMode` and `removedOnCompletion`. These generate many subtle problems if you don't understand exactly what they're doing. They seldom are what you really mean; they just happen to work as long as things are very simple.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for writing but the problem is, that my drawing code (drawInContext:) is never called, even with what you suggested.

Comment: As the radial gradient always starts in the center and extends until min(width,size) of the layer I can leave the startPoint/endPoint uninitialized. Starting an animation leads to an animation which runs behind my radial gradient. It is drawn on top and stays unchanged.

Comment: Hi Rob, me again. Just forget extending CAGradientLayer. Instead use a normal CALayer to implement it. It works.

Comment: Is there any possible performance penalty when only changing the colors of a CAGradientLayer with a CATransaction compared to CABasicAnimation? It look like CATransaction is heavier than CABasicAnimation.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question; why do you believe that a transaction is heavier than a basic animation? Every animation sequence includes a transaction; it's a fundamental part of a CAAnimation. If you don't create one explicitly, one will be created implicitly by the system. The "basic" in "BasicAnimation" is about "simple to use."